# Disable sound from firefox? (selenium webdriver programming)

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I was wondering if there is a way to disable sound from firefox through profile setup in selenium?

Comment: didn't try that but: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/muter/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set 'media.volume_scale' firefox attribute to "0.0"

`FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("media.volume_scale", "0.0");`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in Flash or any other videos/ads displayed, you can try to block that content using AdBlock or Flash Block.

if you have the plugin, you can specifically only block the video that annoys you or all videos in that page specifically but not all of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

as of 2018.07. 29,

if you have updated your selenium and firefox driver(geckodriver)

you should use

`profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("media.volume_scale", "0.0")`